# Using 'tabs' until certain point

Tags: c++

The problem I have right now is, lets say

I have string:
7654367636654543.... (I don't know when its going to end).

What I want to to is:

> 765436763
>
> ```
>          6654543
> ```

Splitting the string into two parts(randomly),
I want the second part (6654543) to start on the next line, but at the place where the first part ends by using \t.

The problem is, I don't know how long the string is going to be, and I don't know how much space the \t takes.

I need help..
thank you

Comment: How much space `\t` takes depends on the output device. I would think you would need to use spaces, not tabs for this.

Comment: Do you really have to use `\t` ? Otherwise you could use `setw()` with a bit of tweaking.

Comment: You can't set nor query the width of `'\t'` in plain C++, your best bet would be to use spaces since you want a specific amount of spaces anyway.